# SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Tags: javascript, if-statement, token

I'm currently learning javascript and I keep having this error!!!

This is my script:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) 
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock")   
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins"; 
        }   
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2){

    if (choice1 === choice2) { return "The result is a tie!"; }
    else if (choice1 === "rock")
        if (choice2 === "scissors") { return "rock wins"; }
    else
        return "paper wins";
}
```

Or neater:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2){

    if(choice1 === choice2){
        return "The result is a tie!"
    }else if(choice1 === "rock"){
        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins"
        }
    }else{
        return "paper wins"
    }
}
```

Comment: @BrandonMagro please check [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). If your problem is solved, you could mark the correct answer.